# Bot pings? evaluation time, latency, and api latency! Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[image]

There is a bot who tells the ping when the message was sent in discord. How can i make something like that?

I just wanna do the same with a embed only

Answer (score 1):

Im not quite sure what `Bot evaluation time` means, but I can help you with the other ones.

You can calculate the **Latency** with `Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp` and the **API Latency** with `Math.round(client.ws.ping)`.

Now you can put it in your embed the way you like!